# Rust can't insert different structs into hashmap

Tags: rust, reference, borrow-checker, ownership, borrowing

Suppose I have a struct and I want to hash it into 2 `HashMap`s, such that the first one holds a reference to it and the second one owns it, like that:

```rust
struct Person { id: i32 }

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut first_name_table = HashMap::new();
    let mut last_name_table = HashMap::new();

    let person1 = Person { id: 1};
    let first_name1 = "first1";
    let last_name1 = "last1";

    last_name_table.insert(last_name1, &person1);
    first_name_table.insert(first_name1, person1);

    Ok(())
}
```

This works fine and as expected. But, when I try to insert a second person, the borrow checker freaks out:

```rust
struct Person { id: i32 }

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut first_name_table = HashMap::new();
    let mut last_name_table = HashMap::new();

    let person1 = Person { id: 1};
    let first_name1 = "first1";
    let last_name1 = "last1";

    last_name_table.insert(last_name1, &person1);
    first_name_table.insert(first_name1, person1);
    
    let person2 = Person { id: 2};
    let first_name2 = "first2";
    let last_name2 = "last2";

    last_name_table.insert(last_name2, &person2);
    first_name_table.insert(first_name2, person2);

    Ok(())
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `person1` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:20:42
   |
19 |     last_name_table.insert(last_name1, &person1);
   |                                        -------- borrow of `person1` occurs here
20 |     first_name_table.insert(first_name1, person1);
   |                                          ^^^^^^^ move out of `person1` occurs here
...
26 |     last_name_table.insert(last_name2, &person2);
   |     --------------- borrow later used here
```

But line 26 has nothing to do with `person1` so why does this happen?

Comment: "This works fine and as expected." I think you ought to find this surprising, actually. You're referencing some local variable and then moving it to someplace else while the reference is still alive. I'm not sure what you would expect this to do.

Answer (score 2):

When you move `person1` into `first_name_table` you invalidate the reference `&person1` stored in `last_name_table` but if you never use `last_name_table` again then the compiler lets the code compile, but as soon as you attempt to use `last_name_table` the compile will throw an error because it contains an invalid reference. It doesn't matter how or when you try to use it. Even simply dropping it will also trigger the error:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Person { id: i32 }

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut first_name_table = HashMap::new();
    let mut last_name_table = HashMap::new();

    let person1 = Person { id: 1};
    let first_name1 = "first1";
    let last_name1 = "last1";

    last_name_table.insert(last_name1, &person1);
    first_name_table.insert(first_name1, person1);
    
    drop(last_name_table); // triggers error

    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised the first version compiles at all, considering you store a reference to the person and then immediately move it. I guess the compiler can see that the reference isn't used beyond that point (**edit:** this is because of `#[may_dangle]` within the map's `Drop` implementation). Regardless, its not quite the second insert but *any* use of `last_name_table` will [trigger an error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3c0cf3a34cf7d80fcc61c048897148c7):

```
let mut first_name_table = HashMap::new();
let mut last_name_table = HashMap::new();

let person1 = Person { id: 1};
let first_name1 = "first1";
let last_name1 = "last1";

last_name_table.insert(last_name1, &person1);
first_name_table.insert(first_name1, person1);

println!("{:?}", last_name_table);
```

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `person1` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:15:42
   |
14 |     last_name_table.insert(last_name1, &person1);
   |                                        -------- borrow of `person1` occurs here
15 |     first_name_table.insert(first_name1, person1);
   |                                          ^^^^^^^ move out of `person1` occurs here
16 |     
17 |     println!("{:?}", last_name_table);
   |                      --------------- borrow later used here
```

You *could* try to insert it into one then get the reference to avoid the move issue:

```
let person1_ref = first_name_table.entry(first_name1).or_insert(person1);
last_name_table.insert(last_name1, person1_ref);
```

But that won't let you modify `first_name_table` any more since `last_name_table` is immutably referencing it. Almost any operation on hash maps *could* end up moving existing elements meaning the reference would become invalid. Rust will prevent you from doing this.

The fix is to clear up your ownership model. I'd recommend using [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) such that each map *shares* ownership of the person. See it working on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0cfbe5cdf1c9a2372c10d3f320fd2472):

```
let mut first_name_table = HashMap::new();
let mut last_name_table = HashMap::new();

let person1 = Rc::new(Person { id: 1});
let first_name1 = "first1";
let last_name1 = "last1";

last_name_table.insert(last_name1, Rc::clone(&person1));
first_name_table.insert(first_name1, person1);

let person2 = Rc::new(Person { id: 2});
let first_name2 = "first2";
let last_name2 = "last2";

last_name_table.insert(last_name2, Rc::clone(&person2));
first_name_table.insert(first_name2, person2);
```